# Magento2: What is the difference between Magento 2.2 and 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, comparison

What is the difference between **Magento 2.2** and **2.3**?

Are Magento 2.3 **DB schema** and **coding structure** same as compare to Magento 2.2?

Are Magento 2.2 extension **supported with Magento 2.3**?

Can we customize own extension in Magento 2.3?

Comment: community release the version for improve performance,add more functionality and fix the bug so can not elaborate difference

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Feature wise difference between Magento 2.2 and Magento 2.3

[image]

**Declarative DB Schema**

Magento 2.3 introduces a new approach – declarative database schema, allowing developers to define database structures and changes in XML files, instead of defining with install scripts. Magento 2.3 will convert the XML schema files into SQL statements and perform them.

The new declarative schema provides a big advantage: rollback support. This means you can roll back database changes you implement on a module or functionality to a previous version

And yes you can customize your own extension

**I hope this will help**

Comment: So we can use the same magento 2.2 db for 2.3 as well right?

Comment: @VIPINAROY yes until unless you use the 3rd party extension which also effect database creating and modifying tables

Comment: we can resolve that by running setup:upgrade command right?

Comment: Google ReCaptcha is introduced in Magento 2.2 or Magento 2.3